# How can I modify an HTML element from an external Javascript File?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show an input when a checkbox is checked. So, I have created a js function to do it and when I write that function on the HTML file it works. But I want to write that function into an external Javascript file an use it from there. How can I do it?

HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Complement Selection</title>

        </head>
        <body>
    <form class="formComplement" action="../php/complementSelectionSave.php" method="POST">
                <div class="mainContainer">
<input type="checkbox" name="hood" id="hood" onclick="showInput()">
                            <label for="hood">Hood</label><br>
                            <div class="inputBox" id="hoodNum" style="display:none">
                                <input type="number" name="hoodNumber" id="hoodNumber" required="" value="">
                                <label for="hoodNumber">Number of Hoods</label>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Next" class="nextButton"/>
            </form>
            <script src="showInput.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript file:

```
function showInput() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("hood");
    var inputBox = document.getElementById("hoodNum");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        inputBox.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        inputBox.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

EDIT: It appears this error:

> showInput.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of
>   null
>       at showInput.js:4

Comment: What do you mean by saying external Javascript file? You want to change a dom from iframe or what?

Comment: "But I want to write that function into an external Javascript file an use it from there. How can I do it?" — Exactly as you have the code in the question.

Comment: What's the issue? It looks like your code works

Comment: It should work, but it doesn´t

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've done. If you're getting some sort of error, please tell us exactly what's happening. "Doesn't work" is not enough information. Do you understand how to use your browser's Developer Tools to check for errors?

Comment: You never call the function showInput. Call it after defining it and it will work !

Comment: @Sorikairo it's called inline from within the HTML (`onclick="showInput()"`) ...old-school, but perfectly valid.

Comment: I mean, when I put the js code on the html file, when the checkbox is checked it shows the div inputBox. But when I put it in that JS filet, when the checkbox is checked, the div inputbox does not show

Comment: @ADyson you are right, mb, missed that.

Comment: @d1845412 — Then the most likely reason is that `showInput.js` is not a URL that resolves to that JS file.

Comment: @Quentin It is, that´s not the problem

Comment: You have wrong dom structure. Multipe closing divs, but not opening ones.

Comment: @Andris there are some issues with that, but it's unlikely to be the cause of the problem, since OP notes the code works when included within a script tag inline in the page.

Comment: When checking for errors with the Developer Tools, make sure you examine the Network tab to see what response you get for the rest for the JS.

Comment: Re edit: Given the code you've provided, that error makes no sense. We can see a single element with that id, and we can see that you don't call that function except from an onclick event that won't fire before the element exists in the DOM. The error doesn't match the code provided.

Comment: According to your error, element doesn't exist in code, before you are calling showInput() method. onclick it should exist. Only option is that you called it before dom existed, like on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only thing why you need javascript here is to change class, to show / hide element than instead what you can do is to write code in pure css and html, using input:checked to change visibility.

Also nextButton should be targetable by css, like element or its parent is same lvl and after input

```css
    #hood:checked ~ .nextButton {
        display: block;
    }
    .nextButton {display: none;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="hood" id="hood">
<label for="hood">Hood</label><br>
<input type="submit" value="Next" class="nextButton"/>
```

Comment: Why downvote, if this works even when browser js is turned off? :P

Answer (score -1):

Try `onchange` instead of `onclick`, and clear up the HTML - the function works as intended! :)

```js
function showInput() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("hood");
  var inputBox = document.getElementById("hoodNum");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    inputBox.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    inputBox.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="formComplement" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hood" id="hood" onchange="showInput()">
    <label for="hood">Hood</label><br>
    <div class="inputBox" id="hoodNum" style="display:none">
      <input type="number" name="hoodNumber" id="hoodNumber" required="" value="">
      <label for="hoodNumber">Number of Hoods</label>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Next" class="nextButton" />
</form>
```

(I deleted the action from the `form`, as it made no sense in the snippet.)